# The pointwise limit of an arbitrary collection of l.s.c. functions is l.s.c.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

It's well-known that the supremum of arbitrary collection of l.s.c. functions is l.s.c. At page 47 of these lecture [notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6FpiqPG4GVDEBk1qgsGU141oVKyxVG-/view?usp=sharing), it is said that

> The pointwise limit of an arbitrary collection of lower semi-continuous functions is lower semi-
> continuous.
> [image]

I could not find any reference for this result. I suspect that this statement may be not true. Could you elaborate on my concern?

Comment: The pointwise limit of $x \mapsto x^n$ on $[0,1]$ is not lsc.

Comment: @copper.hat could you post your counter-example as an answer?

Comment: I added some notes relevant to the lecture notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x <0\\
x^n, & 0 \le x<1 \\
1 , & 1 \le x\end{cases}$ and note that each $f_n$ is continuous, hence lsc.

Then $f_n(x) \to f(x) = 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ which is not lsc.

**Aside**:

The result in the notes follows from Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis", Theorem 12.2: Let $f$ be a convex function. The conjugate function $f^*$ is then a closed convex function, proper **iff** $f$ is proper. Moreover, $(\operatorname{cl} f)^* = f^*$ and $f^{**} =\operatorname{cl} f$.

Rockafellar's defines $\operatorname{cl} f$ as the constant function $-\infty$ if $f(x) = -\infty$ for some $x$ and the lower semicontinuous hull of $f$ otherwise. In particular, if $f$ is proper, then $\operatorname{cl} f = f$ **iff** $f$ is lsc.